Could past simple be correct here
We had almost reached our destination when the speaker said...
I'd just like to know if We almost reached our destination when the speaker said... could be correct.
I think the first one is better because the action of reaching the destination is completed, but if both actions are quite simultaneous the second one should be correct.

The first is good. For the second: "We were reaching our destination when..."

Why is the second not possible

You can say what you like, but it seems colloquial to me. And implies that you didn't reach the destination, because of the event that you go on to describe.

Why does it imply that I did not reached my destination

Second is not good. Compare: I almost finished the test when the bell rang.  "I almost finished" is not an event that can happen at a particular moment, nor is it an achieved state.  You can say I was almost finished the test when the bell rang. or I had almost finshed the test when the bell rang.

I've italicised your example sentences to clarify what I think you mean to ask.

This is one of those questions where there is a technically correct answer, and a real world answer.
Technically, simple past is not correct here, because simple past tense expresses an action or event that occurred, but "almost reaching" somewhere is not an action you can do, it is only a state you can be in (you have not reached it yet).
Past perfect tense ("had almost reached") actually describes a state, so it needs to be used for this situation.  However, if the word "almost" were not used, then "reached" by itself could either be an event (the point in time when you reach it) or a state (the state of being there because you reached it), so either tense could be used.
However, in the real world, people will sometimes use simple past tense for this sort of thing, and it usually does not sound particularly strange or wrong, even though it is technically not correct.

Good explanation re almost which is what the entire thing revolves around. +1 I do NOT understand why people don't just upvote good answers. :)
